# Random range that iteratively multiplied by itself tends to 1

Tags: probability, exponential-function

I was trying to emulate a random currency value, and first thing I thought was to start with value 1 and then iteratively add, say, `Rand(-.1, .1)`, which is a function call that gives me a random number between `-.1` and `.1`. I then realized this could take my currency's value to less than zero, which would make no sense.

So I figured every new value should be proportional to the old value, and tested multiplying the value times `Rand(0, 2)` iteratively. My intuition behind it was that since is as likely for `Rand(0, 2)` to give a number < 1 than a number > 1, the value is as likely to increase as is to decrease. But then for every test I ran the value dropped quickly to almost zero. So I gave `Rand(0, e)` (`e` is the constant 2.718...) a try and it seemed to magically work (I also tried with `Rand(0, 3)` and it grew way above 1 every time).

This was really just a wild guess, and my question is, was my guess right or is this just a coincidence, and if it was, why does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is right :

$$ Y_n=\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$$ with $X_i$ independent random variable uniform on (a,b).

Let $Z_n=\log(Y_n)$, then $$Z_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \log(X_i)$$

What is the distribution of $\log(X_i)$ ?

$$\mathbf P(\log(X_i)<x)=\mathbf P(X_i<e^x)$$

So for any $x\in(\log(a),\log(b))$, $\mathbf P(\log(X_i)<x)=\frac{e^x-a}{b-a}$

Hence $\log(X_i)$ has a density function $f(x)=\frac{e^x}{b-a}$ if $x\in(log(a),log(b))$, else $f(x)=0$.

Hence $\mathbb E(\log(X_i))=\int_{\log(a)}^{\log(b)}\frac{x.e^x}{b-a}dx=\left[\frac{x.e^x}{b-a}\right]_{\log(a)}^{\log(b)}-\int_{\log(a)}^{\log(b)}\frac{e^x}{b-a}dx=\frac{b\log(b)-a\log(a)}{b-a}-1$

if $a=0$, $\mathbb E(\log(X_i))=\log(b)-1$. Note that variance of $\log(X_i)$ is defined and finite. So we can use the central limit theorem to say that $Z_n$ will ultimately follow a normal distribution of mean $n.(\log(b)-1)$.

Of course if $b=e$, then mean is equal to $0$, and $\lim\mathbf P(-{n}\epsilon<Z_n<{n}\epsilon)=1$. So for $b=e$ :
$$\forall\epsilon\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbf P(e^{-\epsilon.{n}}<Y_n<e^{\epsilon.{n}})=1$$

Any other value of $b$ will make $Y_n$ quickly grows towards 0 or $+\infty$.

In particular, for $b=e$, $Y_n$ can grow quite large or small (due to the exponential factor), but it will eventually come back to 1.

EDIT :

For what you want to do, it would be better to simulate the logarithm of the value. Start from $v=0$, and at each step, add a random value between $-1$ and $1$. The value of your currency would be then $e^v$. It would be much more stable around $1$.

Comment: "So we can use the central limit theorem to say that Zn will ultimately follow a uniform distribution" This is definitely not what the CLT is saying.

Comment: ok, it's $\frac{Z_n}{n}$.

Comment: Nope, Zn/n is as far as can be from being uniform.

Comment: Oh, sorry , I mean normal of course ^^

Comment: Then (Zn-nE(logX))/sqrt(n).

Comment: Yes, I could use $\sqrt{n}$, it gives better bounds. But in this case, the limit is not 1 anymore !

Comment: If you say you use the CLT, use the CLT. Fortunately, here you are using the LLN, not the CLT.

Comment: I'm wondering if I can use AC and GCH too to improve my answer.

Comment: So this is why I was having so much trouble trying to figure out myself why it works...

Comment: AC=? GCH=? $ $ $ $